# Codeigniter REST API response log

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, response

I'm using codeigniter REST-API (Author: philsturgeon [Ref](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver))

I have a query/question with the given set of API code.

I know that there is a function and a log table 'logs' to store the API request(with the request parameters). This works good.

I would like to know is there a way to get the response from the API and store it in the same table.

In other words, the request log is created and its a default in-built functionality in codeigniter. I need help with storing the response also. Is there a way?

Comment: Can you paste your code here?

Comment: @senthilbp - thanks for your response. I have added my code here
http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=tuGCKx70
Please check and guide me if you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you add another parameter for pass response in `_log_request` function i.e.

`_log_request($authorized = FALSE)`

to

`_log_request($authorized = FALSE,$response="")`

You can pass your response output in response function  i.e.

`$this->_log_request($authorized = TRUE,$output);`

add 'response' field in your DB table to store response

Here is updated Code :

```
// Request Parameter Log function
protected function _log_request($authorized = FALSE,$response="")
    {
        return $this->rest->db->insert(config_item('rest_logs_table'), array(
                    'uri' => $this->uri->uri_string(),
                    'method' => $this->request->method,
                    'params' => $this->_args ? (config_item('rest_logs_json_params') ? json_encode($this->_args) : serialize($this->_args)) : null,
                    'ip_address' => $this->input->ip_address(),
                    'time' => function_exists('now') ? now() : time(),
                    'authorized' => $authorized,
                    'response' => $response
                ));
    }

// Response function 
public function response($data = array(), $http_code = null)
    {
        global $CFG;

        // If data is empty and not code provide, error and bail
        if (empty($data) && $http_code === null)
        {
            $http_code = 404;

            // create the output variable here in the case of $this->response(array());
            $output = NULL;
        }

        // If data is empty but http code provided, keep the output empty
        else if (empty($data) && is_numeric($http_code))
        {
            $output = NULL;
        }

        // Otherwise (if no data but 200 provided) or some data, carry on camping!
        else
        {
            // Is compression requested?
            if ($CFG->item('compress_output') === TRUE && $this->_zlib_oc == FALSE)
            {
                if (extension_loaded('zlib'))
                {
                    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']) AND strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip') !== FALSE)
                    {
                        ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
                    }
                }
            }

            is_numeric($http_code) OR $http_code = 200;

            // If the format method exists, call and return the output in that format
            if (method_exists($this, '_format_'.$this->response->format))
            {
                // Set the correct format header
                header('Content-Type: '.$this->_supported_formats[$this->response->format]);

                $output = $this->{'_format_'.$this->response->format}($data);
            }

            // If the format method exists, call and return the output in that format
            elseif (method_exists($this->format, 'to_'.$this->response->format))
            {
                // Set the correct format header
                header('Content-Type: '.$this->_supported_formats[$this->response->format]);

                $output = $this->format->factory($data)->{'to_'.$this->response->format}();
            }

            // Format not supported, output directly
            else
            {
                $output = $data;
            }
        }

        header('HTTP/1.1: ' . $http_code);
        header('Status: ' . $http_code);

        // If zlib.output_compression is enabled it will compress the output,
        // but it will not modify the content-length header to compensate for
        // the reduction, causing the browser to hang waiting for more data.
        // We'll just skip content-length in those cases.
        if ( ! $this->_zlib_oc && ! $CFG->item('compress_output'))
        {
            header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($output));
        }
        if (config_item('rest_enable_logging'))
        {
        $this->_log_request($authorized = TRUE,$output);
        }

        exit($output);
    }
```

Comment: you are ma savior. Thanks for the explanation and code. It really worked !!! You are awesome man !!! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Great suggestion, senthilbp. But I think much better to have only one record per API request, with your code for each request will be created 2 records with all the same fields except 'response'. So there is my option.
The good practice is not change original source code but use the beauty of OOP and inherit own class

```
abstract class MY_REST_Controller extends REST_Controller
{
    /**
     * PK from $config['rest_logs_table'] table for last inserted log.
     *
     * @var integer|null
     */
    protected $_log_id;

    /**
     * Log request
     *
     * Record the entry for awesomeness purposes
     *
     * @param boolean $authorized
     * @return object
     */
    protected function _log_request($authorized = FALSE)
    {
        $res = $this->rest->db->insert(config_item('rest_logs_table'), array(
                    'uri' => $this->uri->uri_string(),
                    'method' => $this->request->method,
                    'params' => $this->_args ? (config_item('rest_logs_json_params') ? json_encode($this->_args) : serialize($this->_args)) : null,
                    'api_key' => isset($this->rest->key) ? $this->rest->key : '',
                    'ip_address' => $this->input->ip_address(),
                    'time' => function_exists('now') ? now() : time(),
                    'authorized' => $authorized
                ));
        $this->_log_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        return $res;
    }

    /**
     * Log request response, update existing record, created by @see _log_request()
     *
     * @param string $response
     * @return object
     */
    protected function _log_response($response="")
    {
        if(!$this->_log_id)
        {
            return;
        }
        $log_data['response'] = $response;
        $this->rest->db->where('id', $this->_log_id);
        $this->rest->db->where('response', NULL);// to prevent overwriting
        return $this->rest->db->update(config_item('rest_logs_table'), $log_data);
    }

    /**
     * Response
     *
     * Takes pure data and optionally a status code, then creates the response.
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @param null|int $http_code
     */
    public function response($data = array(), $http_code = null)
    {
        global $CFG;

        // If data is empty and not code provide, error and bail
        if (empty($data) && $http_code === null)
        {
            $http_code = 404;

            // create the output variable here in the case of $this->response(array());
            $output = NULL;
        }

        // If data is empty but http code provided, keep the output empty
        else if (empty($data) && is_numeric($http_code))
        {
            $output = NULL;
        }

        // Otherwise (if no data but 200 provided) or some data, carry on camping!
        else
        {
            // Is compression requested?
            if ($CFG->item('compress_output') === TRUE && $this->_zlib_oc == FALSE)
            {
                if (extension_loaded('zlib'))
                {
                    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']) AND strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip') !== FALSE)
                    {
                        ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
                    }
                }
            }

            is_numeric($http_code) OR $http_code = 200;

            // If the format method exists, call and return the output in that format
            if (method_exists($this, '_format_'.$this->response->format))
            {
                // Set the correct format header
                header('Content-Type: '.$this->_supported_formats[$this->response->format]);

                $output = $this->{'_format_'.$this->response->format}($data);
            }

            // If the format method exists, call and return the output in that format
            elseif (method_exists($this->format, 'to_'.$this->response->format))
            {
                // Set the correct format header
                header('Content-Type: '.$this->_supported_formats[$this->response->format]);

                $output = $this->format->factory($data)->{'to_'.$this->response->format}();
            }

            // Format not supported, output directly
            else
            {
                $output = $data;
            }
        }

        header('HTTP/1.1: ' . $http_code);
        header('Status: ' . $http_code);

        // If zlib.output_compression is enabled it will compress the output,
        // but it will not modify the content-length header to compensate for
        // the reduction, causing the browser to hang waiting for more data.
        // We'll just skip content-length in those cases.
        if ( ! $this->_zlib_oc && ! $CFG->item('compress_output'))
        {
            header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($output));
        }

        if (config_item('rest_enable_logging'))
        {
            $this->_log_response($output);
        }

        exit($output);
    }    
}
```

I hope code is enough clear but I will focus on key areas:

1. Added class field `$_log_id;`
2. The method `_log_request()` modified to store ID of inserted log
3. Added method `_log_response()` to update log record with response
4. Method `_log_response()` called inside `response()`

Voila!

Comment: Your code is not storing any data either in response field